# How to postpone an event "Checkbox.Checked" until certain method (Load) is called

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling

I have a code where the application is crashing because, the subscribe event should be postponed until a load method is called (While currently I am using the checkbox check property inside another method due to business rules as follows:)

```
private void NatureCheck(bool Rec)
{
    chkRec.Checked = !(lblRecID.Visible = txtRecID.Visible = Rec);
        if (!applyReadOnly)
            recipientController.SaveOrNotInBook(chkRec.Checked, address);
}
```

The event below is triggered and app crashes.

```
chkRec.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(chkRec_CheckedChanged);
```

I want to postpone triggering of this above event until "Load method" is called. How to do this, please help me.

My Load Method:

```
private void Rec_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (chkRec.Visible = allowTemp)
        chkRec.Enabled = !(chkRec.Checked = RecDataTable[0].CA_FLAG);  
    string country = RecDataTable[0].IsNTY() ? string.Empty : RecDataTable[0].NTY; 
    showTax(country); 
    dGSignatureLoaded = !(lblDGSignText.Visible = RecDataTable[0].IsDG_SIGNNull()); 
}
```

Event Handler:

```
private void chkRec_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Controller.TryHandleException(delegate
    {

        lblRec.Visible = txtRecID.Visible = !chkRec.Checked;
        if (recipientController.SaveOrNotInBook(chkRec.Checked, RecipientDataTable[0]))
            recDataTableBindingSource.EndEdit();
    });
}
```

Comment: I think it would be very helpful if you posted your load method and your event handler so we can work out what's going on in those methods.

Comment: @Baldrick: Thank you, I pasted my code above. Looks like it gives exception in event handler and the exception reads "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @Baldrick: Sorry, upon debugging, I found that exception happens when the method "NatureCheck()" is hitted in the caller.

Comment: Can you try to work out what's null? Is it chkRec? Where are you calling NatureCheck from?

Comment: @Baldrick: Thank you so much Baldrick, it works fine now. I found that in the method that calls this "NatureCheck", there was a property null and I fixed it, it works fine now. thank you so much :) :) :) But strange, without even unsubscribing it works fine now.

Comment: You're welcome. Best of luck with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is just to move this line:

```
 chkRec.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(chkRec_CheckedChanged);
```

into the end of the Load method. Then the handler isn't attached till the Load has happened.

Note also you can detach the handler at any time as follows:

```
chkRec.CheckedChanged -= new System.EventHandler(chkRec_CheckedChanged);
```

... then reattach again using the original line of code!

Comment: Hi thank you Baldrick, unfortunately its not working :( It throws same exception. My Load method is : private void Rec_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkTempRec.Visible = allowTemp)

                chkTempRec.Enabled = !(chkTempRec.Checked = RecDataTable[0].CA_FLAG);

            //Show the correct tax fields
            string country = RecDataTable[0].IsNTY() ? string.Empty : RecDataTable[0].NTY;

            showTax(country);

            dGSignatureLoaded = !(lblDGSignText.Visible = RecDataTable[0].IsDG_SIGNNull());
        }

Answer (score 1):

Did the event handler existed when initialing the form?
How about remove the handler before the code?

```
private void NatureCheck
{
    chkRec.CheckedChanged -= new System.EventHandler(chkRec_CheckedChanged);
    chkRec.Checked = !(lblRecID.Visible = txtRecID.Visible = Recip);
    chkRec.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(chkRec_CheckedChanged);

}
```

Comment: Hi thank you, unfortunately its not working :( It throws same exception. My Load method is : private void Rec_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkTempRec.Visible = allowTemp)

                chkTempRec.Enabled = !(chkTempRec.Checked = RecDataTable[0].CA_FLAG);

            //Show the correct tax fields
            string country = RecDataTable[0].IsNTY() ? string.Empty : RecDataTable[0].NTY;

            showTax(country);

            dGSignatureLoaded = !(lblDGSignText.Visible = RecDataTable[0].IsDG_SIGNNull());
        }

Comment: The first **if** statement be  `if(chkTempRec.Visible == allowTemp)`

Comment: Thank you Jam, that was a good catch, yet I must tell you that, my application was running without any problem even without == but just =. I tried this too, however no luck :( Actually its showing this expception" " and the method is, caller of the NatureCheck method. Does it mean, should I unsubscribe this event in caller?

Comment: Oh no...
Something is not assigned as @Baldrick said.. You better check what is still null reference first..

Comment: Hi Jam, thank you so much, that's correct, my bad. I didn't check it properly. However, I was told to postpone the event, anyway, without that itself it works. I will update it with my supervisor :) Cheers thank you again :)